# Design Edit Text Code Editor with line number not scrollable

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, scrollview, code-editor

I am trying to design a code editor with the help of Android Edit Text. I am using a text view parallel to it which is showing line number. It is working fine but the problem is after going down more then 30 lines it text view remains same but edit text becomes scroll able I can make the text view scroll able but it will not going to scroll with respect to edit text. The main problem is of scrolling. If anyone can help me to correct this or some other way to use similar kind of simple activity to code with line numbers, So that further I will be able to save that text in a file.
Below is the Activity and xml code I have tried.

```
MainActivity.java

package com.rk.codeareadesignworkingedittextline;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                int lines=ed.getLineCount();
                String lineText="";
                for (int i=1;i<=lines;i++){
                    lineText=lineText+i+"\n";
                    tv.setText(lineText);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="587dp"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="595dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: make your TextView and EditText layout_height as match_parent.

Comment: I have done that but it does not resolves scrolling issue... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your EditText in a ScrollView. And let the EditText and TextView expand as much as it can with `wrap_content`.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18dp" />

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Wow it worked very well thanks How can I remove the underline of edit text and One more query if I can highlight a word or change the text color of a part while writing.. Thank you so much

Comment: To remove the underline use `android:background="@null"` in your EditText XML declaration.

Comment: For the second part, it's going to be difficult. You would need to use Spans and set them dynamically every time text is updated.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/tips/1354522786/numbered-spannable-android-edittext

Comment: new NumberingSpan() and .setSelection() methods are not resolvable... what does the snippet actually do Froyo

Comment: @RupeshKumar The blog post shows how you can use Spannables in EditText. You should change NumberingSpan() with ForegroundColor or something. It's not a straightforward answer. You should start small and just try to change the color of the whole text dynamically using Spans.

Comment: Thanks froyo! I found some good examples about spans thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: your code is working I tried.. a little issue is the edit text's text becomes non parallel to the text view line number this problem is occurring when keyboard grab the space.. accepted answer is more efficient... Thanks for your response :)